# What is the memory overhead of a single entry (key-value pair) in Java 7 HashMap? (using 64-bit Oracle Hotspot JVM)

Tags: java

What is the memory overhead of a single entry in Java HashMap? (using 64-bit Oracle Hotspot JVM). For example: is it 24 or 32 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a [`HashMap.Entry`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/a42d6999734b/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l691) (Java 6) or [`HashMap.Node`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l274) (Java 8), both of which has one `int` and three references.

If a reference is 4 bytes (compressed OOPS), then 12 bytes header + 4 byte `int` + 3 * 4 byte reference = 28 bytes, rounded to **32 bytes** to fit on 8-byte boundary.

If a reference is 8 bytes, then 16 bytes header + 4 byte `int` + 3 * 8 byte reference = 44 bytes, rounded to **48 bytes** to fit on 8-byte boundary.

Answer (score 0):

An HashMap collection takes 32 bytes for each entry plus 4 bytes * map capacity for entries array.